# Is there any refreshed event for Calendar Date Picker Next Button UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp, datepicker, calendar, uwp-xaml

I'm using Calendar Date Picker in UWP. When the next button is clicked, its taking time to load dates and next button is still enabled and user can able to click next button before refreshing. Is there any way to handle the next button until dates are loaded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, I have to say there is no such refresh event for the **CalendarView** (When you click a **CalendarDatePicker**, the DatePicker will show a **CalendarView** and the next button is in that **CalendarView**.). **CalendarDatePicker** and **CalendarView** only have a `CalendarViewDayItemChanging event` which is fired when a **CalendarViewDayItem** is loading in the picker's CalendarView and it is not suitable for your requirement.

You could submit a feature request about this in the Feedback Hub.